# Click event handler not persisting for dynamically created checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Javascript script in which I define a class called a "Layer". I put code in the `Layer` constructor, so that each time a new `Layer` object is created a checkbox associated with that layer is added to the HTML document. I also created a JQuery event handler within the constructor so that when the new checkbox is clicked, the layer is either shown or hidden within the document depending on the state of the checkbox. For some reason however, the event handler only works for the most recently created layer. Somehow the old event handlers are getting overwritten. I searched on here for similar questions, and saw that using the `on` function from JQuery rather than `click` is the way to go, but I'm still having the same issue. Here's my code...

```
Layer2D.prototype.addToUI = function() {
    if (this.firstLayer()) {
        var layerDiv = document.createElement('div');
        layerDiv.className = 'content';
        layerDiv.id = 'layerNames';
    }
    else {
        var layerDiv = document.getElementById('layerNames');
    }

    layerDiv.innerHTML += '</br>' +
                          '<div class="ui toggle mini checkbox" id="layer' + this.name +'">' +
                          '<input type="checkbox" name="' + this.name + '" checked>' +
                          '</input>' +
                          '<label>' + this.name + '</label>' +
                          '</div>';

    if (this.firstLayer()) {
        var parentDiv = document.getElementById('layerMenu');
        parentDiv.appendChild(layerDiv);
    };
    $('#layer' + this.name).after('<br/>');

    var This = this;
    $('#layer' + this.name).on('click', ':input', function(e) {
        checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        console.log(This);
        if (checked === true) {
            This.show();
        }
        else { 
            This.hide();
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I don't think so. The solution there was to use the JQuery `on()` method which I'm already using here.

Comment: Please read the full answer. It talks about event delegation, using three arguments to `on`.

Comment: I did but I still only have a vague idea of how it applies here. I think my issue (which from the answers appears to be with innerHTML) is different enough from the one in that question to warrant its own post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use $(document).on('click', '#layer' + this.name, function(){...}) it usually works with dynamically added HTML.

Comment: Great, this works for me! I guess the key was calling the `on()` method on the document object itself rather than on the checkbox. Still not sure why one way would work and the other wouldn't though.

Comment: A short/simple explanation would be that js only knows about what already exists with the attribute filter you've set. If you want js to about more than that you need to broaden it's scope, so it can find your newly created elements.

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML has this issue.  If you create the dynamic elements using Document.create methods, I think the listener will be attached.  In any case you can put your evenListener(s) in a function like addEventListenerToBeer() and call it after the innerHTML call.

```
var d = document.createElement("div")
var t = document.createTextNode("i like beer");
d.id = "myId";
d.appendChild(t);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right about the issue being with `innerHTML`. I'm pretty sure your fix would work, but the above solution is a bit simpler. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Also, now I'm tempted to id all my div elements with names of different IPAs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace:

```
layerDiv.innerHTML += '</br>' +
                      '<div class="ui toggle mini checkbox" id="layer' + this.name +'">' +
                      '<input type="checkbox" name="' + this.name + '" checked>' +
                      '</input>' +
                      '<label>' + this.name + '</label>' +
                      '</div>';
```

for:

```
let element="";
//****
element = '</br>' +
                      '<div class="ui toggle mini checkbox" id="layer' + this.name +'">' +
                      '<input type="checkbox" name="' + this.name + '" checked>' +
                      '</input>' +
                      '<label>' + this.name + '</label>' +
                      '</div>';
$(element).appendTo(layerDiv);
```

appendTo inserts the elements and make them part of the DOM to be query...

Comment: OK thanks, I never would've guessed that this was an innerHTML issue. Your solution sort of works, but in this case the whole innerHTML is duplicated each time a new checkbox is added.

Comment: yes you are right, it doesn't need the `elements=layerDiv.innerHTML;` sorry about that... I'll update my answer...